# How to best optimise PHP program so it doesn't timeout?

Tags: php, api, rest, serverless

I am building an application in PHP that requests data from a third-party API, stores and processes that data and then submits additional API requests based on the data received from the first request.

The issue is that there are several rate limits and where there is a large volume of data to be requested, I need to make many paginated API requests in 2-second intervals so that I can avoid getting blocked by the rate limits. Essentially, the programme keeps looping through making APi requests every 2 seconds until there is no longer a next page URl in the response header.

Depending on the amount of data, it could take several minutes, up to several hours. I can increase the max execution time in PHP.ini, but this is not efficient and could still result in a timeout if one day the program has too much data to work with.

I'm sure there must be a better way to manage this, possibly with serverless functions, or some kind of queuing system to run in the background. I have never worked with serverless functions, so it will be a learning curve, but happy to learn if needed.

I would love to hear what anyone thinks the best solution is. I am building the application in PHP, but I can work with JS, or NodeJs if I need to.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If anything can take up-to several hours, then run it as a batch process. I mean by that as a PHP CLI script not a web based process. There are no time limits set for a CLI Script.

Comment: This question is overly broad as written and going to receive  opinion based answers as asked; one way or another the direction you need to go in, imo, is to make the system function asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use queue for that. There are plenty of packages, and you can choose one depends on your needs.

Also, you can use Asynchronous requests maybe from guzzle or some other vendors (which speedup reading process) and also you can easily implement delay retry middleware for rate limiter.